# pydantic dataclass allowing None parameter

Tags: python, pydantic

When using `pydantic.dataclass` I'm specifying that a type must be an `int`.  When the constructor is called with a `None` parameter, the validator **doesn't** raise a `ValidationError`. How can I make the `pydantic.dataclass` raise when None is passed?

```
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    age: int = Field(None, title="the user age", ge=18, le=120)

    def __init__(self, age: int):
        self.age = age


>>> print(MyClass("foo", None))
MyClass(age=None) # Expecting an Error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `None` from the Field declaration

```
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    age: int = Field(title="the user age", ge=18, le=120)
```

```
>>> MyClass(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 313, in pydantic.dataclasses._add_pydantic_validation_attributes.new_init
    f'order={self.order!r},'
  File "pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 416, in pydantic.dataclasses._dataclass_validate_values
    def _field_init(f, frozen, globals, self_name):
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyClass
age
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
>>>
>>> MyClass(20)
MyClass(age=20)
```

Also, you don't need to add an `__init__` to a dataclass.